# Matlab best match of a sequence within a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, edit, distance, levenshtein-distance

I want to find the best match of a sequence of integers within a NxN matrix. The problem is that I don't know how to extract the position of this best match. The following code that I have should calculate the edit distance but I would like to know where in my grid that edit distance is shortest!

```
function res = searchWordDistance(word,grid)

% wordsize = length(word); % extract the actual size
% [x ,y] = find(word(1) == grid);
D(1,1,1)=0;
for i=2:length(word)+1
    D(i,1,1) = D(i-1,1,1)+1;
end
for j=2:length(grid)
    D(1,1,j) = D(1,1,j-1)+1;
    D(1,j,1) = D(1,j-1,1)+1;
end
% inspect the grid for best match
for i=2:length(word)
    for j=2:length(grid)
        for z=2:length(grid)
        if(word(i-1)==grid(j-1,z-1))
            d = 0;
        else
            d=1;
        end
        c1=D(i-1,j-1,z-1)+d;
        c2=D(i-1,j,z)+1;
        c3=D(i,j-1,z-1)+1;
        D(i,j,z) = min([c1 c2 c3]);

        end
    end
end
```

I have used this code (in one less dimension) to compare two strings. 
**EDIT** Using a 5x5 matrix as example

```
15 17 19 20 22
14 8  1  15 24
11 4  17 3  2
14 2  1  14 8
19 23 5  1  22
```

now If I have a sequence `[4,1,1]` and `[15,14,12,14]` they should be found using the algorithm. The first one is a perfect match(diagonal starts at (3,2)). The second one is on the first column and is the closest match for that sequence since only one number is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `find the best match of a sequence of integers within a NxN matrix`. First, define a matrix of `5x5`, give your input array and your desired output `best match`. That will help us to understand your problem more clearly. You should always try to represent your problem with a template with minimal complexity (if possible).

Comment: By closest, do you mean most identical numbers, or smallest total difference? Which is closest to `[1 1 1]`: `[1 2 2]` or ´[1 1 100]´?

Comment: The most identical numbers. The algorithm I have posted does this already. It tells us the distance between two vectors. (how many operations it takes to turn one into the other). So position of numbers also matter. (we might have to insert one in the middle to make them identical). I wanna know if it's possible to do it on a vector and a 2-dim matrix instead of just two vectors.